# rspec don't recognize mailing class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to make a spec for the mailing that is already implemented and I have this:

- rspec-rails 3.5.2
- rails 5
- ruby 2.3.1

**app/mailers/application_mailer.rb**

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'aaa@gmail.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

**app/mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome!')
  end
end
```

**config/environments/test.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  #[...]
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  #[...]
end
```

**spec/mailers/usermailer_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe UserMailer, :type => :mailer do
 #[...]
end
```

When I run

> rspec spec/mailers/usermailer_spec.rb

I receive this error message on the terminal:

> [...]spec/mailers/usermailer_spec.rb:4:in `':
>   uninitialized constant UserMailer (NameError)
>       [...]

Comment: Not sure, but you have `usermailer_spec.rb` & `user_mailer.rb` (don't match) Try maybe renaming spec to `user_mailer_spec.rb` and see if this helps

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and unfortunately it didn't work to me but I'll let it to be user_mailer_spec.rb like you sad.

Comment: Have you ensured that the Mailer files become initialized while loading the test? Also you might wanna try instantiating thr Mailer class in your rails console. If that does not work you should check your path settings

Answer (score 2):

You need to require `require 'rails_helper'` instead of `spec_helper` on the spec file.